# atomでInstall Shell Commands以外からapmを導入する方法はありますか？

Tags: atom-editor

現在誤った操作をしたことからatomを起動することが出来ないでいます。
apmコマンドを使いたいのですが、「Install Shell Commands」でapmの導入をしていないため、apmコマンドが使えません。

外部からapmを導入できる方法もあると思うのですが知識が乏しくわかりません。
自分なりに調べapmをGitHubからクローンしたのですがその後がわかりません。
お手数ですが分かる方いましたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**過去の質問からMac OS Xでのことだと思うので、Mac OS Xについてお答えします。**
今後はOSなども記載していただいたほうが回答は集まりやすいと思います。

`apm`の本体はAtom.app内にあります（`Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/apm`）。
ターミナル（アプリケーション=>ユーティリティ=>ターミナル）で上を直接指定しても良いですし、`/Application`にインストールしてあるのであれば、以下のコマンドで「Install Shell Commands」と同じ結果になります。

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/apm /usr/local/bin/apm
```

「Install Shell Commands」を実行した場合`atom`コマンドも使えるようになりますが、それは以下で再現できます。

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom
```

**ターミナルをはじめてお使いでしたら注意深くお使いください。最悪OSがまともに動かなくなるような操作も可能です。**

Comment: 解決しました！！！本当に助かりました。ありがとうございました。すみません、ご指摘ありがとうございます。今後はOSも記載します。

Comment: @yoshi554231 さん、それは良かったです。もう一つの質問もそうですが、正しかった・最も役に立った回答には左にあるチェックを押してください。回答者のやる気と今後同じ問題にぶつかった方々のためになります。

Comment: @packet0さん、最後までご丁寧にありがとうございます。大変役に立ちましたのでチェックしました。これからもよろしくお願いします。